# Solr Cloud Replication Time

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are using solr cloud with 1 shard and replication factor as 3. We are noticing that the time for data to become available across all replicas from the leader is very high.

The data rate is not very high, is there anyway to control this. In master-slave setup with give a replication time.

EDIT

```
 <autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
       <maxDocs>25000</maxDocs>
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
 </autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit> 
     <maxTime>1000</maxTime> 
   </autoSoftCommit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you have to tweak to decrease the time it takes to replicate are listed here:

[Near Real Time Searching](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching)

Pay attention to commitWithin which does not replicate.

Comment: we are not using the master slave mode. It's a cloud so now sure how this variable would help.

Comment: Can you post your solrconfig related to commits?

Comment: Added details, also one other point that we have noticed is that post restart of the cloud everything work find for a while and then again delay increases.